# How can i implement a magazine view in ios?

Tags: ios

I have so much data in server as a text and image also. I want to retrieve all text/image and show it on a `UITextView/UIImageView`.

But I want it to show as a magazine view like below image:

[image]

[image]

*For img-1:* I am showing only 2 columns in image but its depend on data how many column it'll. may be it'll 10, 2, 4 etc but more than 1.

*For img-2:* In image 2, i want to show image with text. Left side it'll showing image and right side it'll show text.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Theses image are from: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app What's wrong exactly with this tutorial?

Comment: Ya, this images are from raywenderlich for demo image. in that tutorial he is implementing for CoreText like magazine App. but my question is i have to show like that, not magazine app. I have to show the text only like that.

Comment: Well, the first image is quite explicit, no? If you don't want images, just dont put images. The tutorial could go without images.